# Eevee render doesn't look like render preview

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

So when I render the model with EEVEE the render output is different from the render preview in viewport.

Eevee render viewport screenshot:
[image: Render viewport screenshot]

Eevee render output:
[image]

Why are they different?

This last is the output from cycles.

Cycles render:
[image]

How do I achieve something like in the first image with EEVEE and Cycles?!?

Comment: have you tried adjusting your lights? It looks more harsh / powerful in the renders than in the preview.

Comment: @Luciano I didn't touch the lights... I don't know why are lights harsher in the output. I noticed today while playing in the viewport when I check Ambient Occlusion in the World tab that the image in the preview now turns to a harsh image like render? 

How to disable AO in the render?

Comment: The last two images are identical. Did you upload the wrong ones?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Ambient Occlusion is on in the Render panel. That might make the object shadows disappear if it's off.

[image]